# My Internet browser automatically open and close HTML side bar everytime. How can i stop that and what happened?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, browser, backend

Whenever I open any Internet browsers, in the right hand side automatically a side page open for the half of the exact page and it has some HTML code. It opens and closes it self again and again. Why is that? How to stop that? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just the inspect element tool

Try pressing control+shift+i

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persist, try reinstalling your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The problem was in my F12 key. F12 key is malfunctioning.